# Prove that $a ≤ x ≤ b ⇒ |x| ≤ |a|+|b|$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, alternative-proof, absolute-value

Can you please help me with this proof $$a ≤ x ≤ b ⇒ |x| ≤ |a|+|b|$$ ? I am literally stuck for hours.

This is what i thought, but i don't know if it counts as a proof.
First of all, if a ≤ x then  $x ≤ -a$ so $a ≤ x ≤ -a$ if $x ≤ -a$ then $|x| ≤ |-a| = |a|$
Now we look at b:
if x ≤ b then $-b ≤ x ≤ b$ so  $$|-b| = |b| ≤ |x|$$ OR  $$|x| ≤ |-b| = |b|$$
let's choose the "worst" option which is |b| ≤ |x|
so $$|b| ≤ |x| ≤ |a| ⇒  |x| ≤ |a| - |b|  ≤ |a| + |b| ⇒  |x| ≤ |a| +|b|$$

Is it correct? Please show me other ways to prove it.

Comment: I haven't read your argument. I would prove this by drawing a picture of the real line and thinking about the possible signs of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You say if $a\le x$ then $x\le -a$. That's not true. Say $a=1$ and $x=2$

Answer (score 3):

Hint

$x$ can not be further away from $0$ than **both** $a$ and $b$.

Consider that $x$ must have the same sign as at least one of $a,b$.

Comment: Jesus! Thanks, i havent paid enough attention to that.